# GreaterThan with Exceptions

Tags: vb.net, exception

I need to write a program that indicates the larger of two variables using exceptions.

I'm not sure if this is an acceptable code. I'm new at this and attempted with this code here:

```
Class GreaterThan
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim Y As Integer = 12
        Dim X As Integer = 23
        If Y > X Then
            System.Console.WriteLine(Y)
        Else
            System.Console.WriteLine(X)
            Throw New Exception("Greater Than")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

I normally wouldn't use an exception but I am asked to use one, I'm just not sure what kind of exception would work best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question really is.  Your code seems perfectly valid.  It would display:
23 
Greater Than

Generally speaking; you wouldn't want to use an Exception to handle something like comparing integers.

There are lots of ways to skin a cat, but you might want to look at these:

```
        Console.Write(If(Y > X, Y, X))

        Console.Write(Math.Max(X, Y))

        Console.Write(New Integer() {X, Y}.Max())
```

I guess I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish.  If you *have* to use an Exception I might be tempted to do something like...

```
If X > Y Then
    Throw New Exception(String.Format("{0} is greater than {1}", X, Y))
End If
```

Comment: I wouldn't use an exception if I didn't have to. But since I am asked to use one, this is my attempt. I would have done it differently if there was no need for the exception.

Comment: Thank you, I used that in my code and modified it a bit, but I think it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Exceptions in that situation. Instead do something like this:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim Y As Integer = 12
    Dim X As Integer = 23

    If Y > X Then
        System.Console.WriteLine(Y)
    Else
        System.Console.WriteLine(X)
        ' PERFORM ACTION BASED ON X > Y
    End If
End Sub
```

You could also wrap it in a Function that returns True or False depending on what X and Y is, but I think it's a little overkill.

Comment: @user678113 I normally wouldn't use an exception either, but I am asked to use one. I want to know if it's a valid one.

Comment: Aren't all Exceptions valid exceptions?  Can you explain what you mean by "valid exception"?

Comment: By valid I meant if it's the best. I know it doesn't make much sense, but I don't make much sense. My thoughts and explanations are convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the class likes it done:

```
 Class MyClient
   Public Shared Sub Main()
      Try
      Dim X As Integer = 11
      Dim Y As Integer = 12
      If X > Y Then
      System.Console.WriteLine("X is Greater")
      Else
      Throw New Exception("Y is Greater")
      End If
      Catch e As Exception
      System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
      End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```